# HWE for 14.04 ended but update to current security-supported stack does not work

Tags: 14.04, hardware-enablement-stack

I run 14.04 with Hardware Enablement Stack and do want to keep with 14.04 with its current stack. I have:

```
# hwe-support-status --verbose

WARNING: Security updates for your current Hardware Enablement Stack
ended on 2016-08-04:
 * http://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL

To upgrade to a supported (or longer-supported) configuration:

* Upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by running:
sudo do-release-upgrade 

OR

* Switch to the current security-supported stack by running:
sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial linux-generic-lts-xenial

and reboot your system.
```

OK, I am fine with installing some other versions of packages, so I do as I was told:

```
# apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-xenial libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-xenial xserver-xorg-lts-xenial linux-generic-lts-xenial
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-xenial : Hängt ab von: libglapi-mesa-lts-xenial (= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2~trusty1) soll aber nicht installiert werden
 xserver-xorg-lts-xenial : Kollidiert mit: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~)
                           Kollidiert mit: libgles2-mesa (>= 0~)
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

There are dependencies that could not be solved. What can I do?

Comment: Hm, a pity that nobody seems to have a solution. I tried it myself: I did a "dpkg -l |  grep vivid" and removed the packages and installed the packages with no "vivid" in its named. That did the trick.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don’t put the answer in your question or the comments! Send me a message in the comments if you want my up-vote. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, a pity that nobody seems to have a solution. I tried it myself: I did a "dpkg -l | grep vivid" and removed the packages and installed the packages with no "vivid" in its named. That did the trick.